# Align images (maps) coming from a scanned source

Tags: image, image-processing, alignment, gis, image-scanner

I have several images like the one below which are coming from a scanned book. 
The images have been catted with the same image-size but they are slightly distorted and do not overlap perfectly. You can see an animation here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29337496/animation.gif .

Before apply a georeferencing process (by gdal) i need to align them in order to have the country borders in perfect overlap.

I have already test align_image_stack  (hugin sw) with the different flags, 
but i did not get positive results.

Any idea?
I'm using Ubuntu.

Thanks 
Best Giuseppe

[image]

Comment: Which part are you having difficulties with? You can split the images out of the animation pretty simply with one line of ImageMagick, go into Photoshop Bridge and select all the layers and load them into a Stack in Photoshop and then do `Edit->Auto-align Layers`. Do you have lots to do? Or do you need to use some different tools?

Comment: Thanks Mark, yes i have several ones in single layers (.jpg) and i need to align them. A potential semiautomatic solution would be to find a image tool that return the click-xy coordinate in the bash  terminal and than use this to re project the image with gdal. Any one has an idea which sw returns xy coordinates in the terminal?

Comment: I meant that the process is pretty much fully automated in Photoshop. Why do you want to do it in a harder, only semi-automated way that involves writing a load of extra software? I am not being funny - just trying to understand your objection to using Photoshop to align the layers.

Comment: Gimp Plug-in for Image Registration does a good job.